# Struggle with parse function

Tags: android, kotlin

So started learning Kotlin and Android studio coding.

I was following Youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3_QgdmXGK4&t=994s&ab_channel=Dr.ParagShukla

I am making simple age calculator, however, cant make string to become date, so i could subtract input date with current date. Code looks exactly same as in the video.

Code compiles well and gets installed in android device, however, whenever press Calculate Age button, app stops responding because of var dob = sdf.parse(dob) function. I assume it cant convert the date from string to date format for further calculations. Thanks.

Code below:

```kotlin
fun openDatePicker(view: View) {
    var c = Calendar.getInstance()

    DatePickerDialog(
        this,
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, yy, mm, dd -> // listens what date picker has to say

            var mm = mm + 1
            var date = "$dd/ $mm /$yy "

            TimePickerDialog(
                this,
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hh, mi ->
                    date += " $hh:$mi"
                    editTextTextPersonName.setText(date) // shows date in the line
                },
                c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                true
            ).show()
        }, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    ).show()
}


fun Calculateage(view: View) {
    var today = Date() // todays date
    var dobs = editTextTextPersonName.text.toString() // takes value from input
    var sdf = SimpleDateFormat("mm/MM/yy HH:mm")
    var dob = sdf.parse(dobs) // converts the date to simple date, no can find difference

    var days = (today.time - dob.time) / 86400000 // converts into mil secs, need to divide by milsecs in a day
    var hours = (today.time - dob.time) % 86400000 / 3600000
    var minutes = (today.time - dob.time) % 86400000 % 3600000 / 60000
    var sec = (today.time - dob.time) % 86400000 % 3600000 % 60000/1000

    textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    textView.setText("Days = $days\nHours= $hours\nMinutes=$minutes\nSeconds = $sec")
}
```

Comment: You did not tell us what the issue is.

Comment: Please be more concrete about your problem and add the full error message.

Comment: Code compiles well and gets installed in android device, however, whenever press Calculate Age button, app stops responding because of var dob = sdf.parse(dob) function. I assume it cant convert the date from string to date format for further calculations. Thanks

Comment: Probably it is because you let the simple date formatter search for `"mm/MM/yy HH:mm"`. But you provide a string `"$dd/ $mm /$yy $hh:$mi "`.  You see the additional space characters and the "mm/" instead of "dd/"?

Comment: Thanks Peter, will investigate. I was following Youtube video, which i will include in the main post, as just started learning

Answer (score 0):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't match your string value.

Your `var date` looks like `var date = "$dd/ $mm /$yy  $hh:$mi"`

Your SimpleDateFormat has `"mm/MM/yy HH:mm"`

You should change your formatter to something like this:
`"dd/ MM /yy  HH:mm"`

Comment: I changed the code as advised, as it was left off typo from many things i tried. So my  var date = "$dd/ $mm /$yy  $hh:$mi" and my SimpleDateFormat dd/MM/yy HH:mm . Unfortunately app still compiles, but crashes. is there other way to make var date to become same as simpleDateFormat so i could just substract 2 dates?

Comment: And does it work after changes? There still seems to be extra spaces between $dd/ $mm /$yy in your var date. Either remove those spaces or add them to the SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Thanks Kubik, big help, did not even realize that spaces can make such a difference! Program works fine now! Appreciate help!